# Error when compiling blender for windows - OSL not found

Tags: python, windows, compiler-errors, blender

I am trying to compile blender for windows. I have followed the instructions on the [blender wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Windows)

When I run the the command "make full" in the command prompt I get the following error:

```
-- 64 bit compiler detected.
-- Visual Studio 2013 detected.
CMake Warning at build_files/cmake/platform/platform_win32.cmake:436 (message):
  LLVM debug libs not present on this system.  Using release libs for debug
  builds.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:931 (include)


-- OSL not found 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1573 (message):
  Missing:
  "E:/blender-git/blender/../lib/win64_vc12/python/include/python3.6/Python.h",


  Set the cache entry 'PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR' to point to a valid python include
  path.  Containing Python.h for python version "3.6"


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "E:/blender-git/build_windows_Full_x64_vc12_Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.40629.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: E:\blender-git\blender\..\build_windows_Full_x64_vc12_Release\Blender.sln
"Build Failed"
```

It seems to me that CMake can't find the needed python files. I have Python 3.6 installed. It seems that I should be able to change the value of 'PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR' to point to the python installation folder, but there is no hint in which file this should be changed.

Comment: I'll sound pragmatic, but it's much easier to use the already prepared image for your Windows platform. [Here you can download it](https://www.blender.org/download/).

Answer (score 0):

You can change that in the advanced options within CMake itself. But are you sure you followed the right steps, it seems you forgot to get the svn lib files for your platform.